# Hide mu-plugins list

Tags: mu-plugins

I'm using mu-plugins, http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins.

These plugins are showing in plugins.php, http://d.pr/i/JIvX.

Is there any way to hide it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this request is filtering `show_advanced_plugins`. This filter is called twice, once for `mustuse`- and once for `dropins`-plugins.

The filter accepts two parameters, the first one being the standard value (`true`), and the second one being the type of the advanced plugin (Must-Use and Drop-In).

So returning false does the trick, if your condition is met. If you want Dropt-Ins to be hidden as well, just set the function to `return false`.

Please be aware that a Plugin can alter this filter, so you may have to change the priority to achieve the desired results (3rd parameter). Also return the `$default` value in the standard case, to allow other functions the same functionality.

And here comes the code:

```
add_filter( 'show_advanced_plugins', 'f711_hide_advanced_plugins', 10, 2 );

function f711_hide_advanced_plugins( $default, $type ) {
    if ( $type == 'mustuse' ) return false; // Hide Must-Use
    return $default;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely right, Actually found it already but I can't right answer before 8 hours. Anyways thanks it will help for someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the `views_plugins` filter and unset the mustuse item:

```
function my_remove_mu_plugins( $views ){
    if ( isset($views['mustuse']) )
        unset($views['mustuse']);
    return $views;
}
add_filter('views_plugins','my_remove_mu_plugins');
```

Note: It will still be possible to access the mu plugins list by entering an url like `plugins.php?plugin_status=mustuse`.